# Ubuntu 14.04 UFW issues / Syslog

Tags: 14.04, server, iptables, ufw

I have a strange behavior with UFW...
I added rules for a specific port (12666 TCP and UPD v4/v6) and in the syslog file I can see that UFW blocks many or all connections to this port...

How could it be?

I checked the iptables rules, and everything is here... 
I red many articles, but did not find any answer :s

Thx.

Comment: You could try to restart ufw with `sudo service ufw restart` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo ufw status verbose` ?

Comment: @jeroen: https://tmp.kcin.fr/ufw.png (screenshot)